# finding longest interrupt in linux

Tags: linux, isr, ftrace

I have a system where I have an interrupt which is taking a long time (several ms), and is causing some real-time issues.  The problem is that I don't know which interrupt it is.  I'm using ftrace, with the irqsoff, and it's reporting that the longest irq-off period starts at handle_int and ends at __do_softirq (hence, it's in an interrupt).  Is there an easy way to determine which interrupt is causing the delay?   (note: the kernel version is 3.4)

Comment: Have you seen [SystemTrap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/)?

Comment: Looks interesting.  I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Here is example from manual of `trace-cmd-record`:

```
trace-cmd record -p function_graph -e irq_handler_entry  -l do_IRQ sleep 10
```